# setting a parent property in a directive in angular with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

Given the following `html` which declares a directive.

```
<div class="form-group"
     data-panda-map-search map="map"
     search-hint="#BuildingName"
     imageUri="{{imageUri}}"
     location-target="#Geolocation">
</div>
```

And the following binding (at the same level in the `html`:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <img ng-src="{{imageUri}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

**My goal is to set** the `imageUri` value in the **directive** and have it update the image src in **the parent scope**. to change the image.

I have declared the scope like this:

```
@directive('$http', '$log', 'ISearchService')
export class PandaMapSearch implements ng.IDirective
{
    scopeCopy: any;
    public restrict: string = "A";
    public scope: any =
    {
        map: "=",
        imageUri: "=",
    }
    public link: Function = (scope: any, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {
        this.map = scope.map;
        this.scopeCopy = scope;
    }

    public setUri() {
        // attempt to set the value, and change the parent.
        this.scopeCopy.imageUri = 'new url';
    }
```

Later on in the directive, in an event - I set `this.scopeCopy.imageUri`, and get the following error:

> Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'pandaMapSearch' is non-assignable!
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=pandaMapSearch

**update**

I have also tried `this.scopeCopy.$parent.imageUri = ...` this seems to set the parent value, but the digest is never executed. The parent scope has the value set, but the binding is never updated so the src attribute remains unchanged.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle to demo your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue could be related to the 2 way binding property `imageUri="{{imageUri}}"` @ `imageUri: "=",`. You have `imageUri` mentioned as a 2 way bound property so you should just bind the property instead of binding it as expression value by using the interpolation. i.e `{{..}}`. 2 way bound property needs a property which can be assigned a value, so instead of binding a property there you have provided an interpolated expression.

Try binding property as:

```
imageUri="imageUri"
```

or change your `imageUri` binding to `@` binding (text binding), i.e

```
public scope: any = {
    map: "=",
    imageUri: "@", //<-- Here
    locationTarget: "@",
    searchHint: "@"
}
```

Comment: if I change the scope to use "@" then it just passes a string, so how do get the directive to update the parent scope value?

Comment: If u want 2 way binding then u have to use =. But u shoukd bind property not text as i mentioned in my answer `imageUri="imageUri"`.

Comment: yes, I have done that, and now it seems to be correctly updating the parent scope(s) value. My problem is that it is not firing the digest for the parent and actually doing the update. I need to somehow trigger the parent digest when I set the value. If I manually trigger the parent with $('body').scope().apply() it updates the page.

Comment: Ok. Your original question was about the error for which i gave the answer. However your manually digest may be due to the update to the property happening outside of the angular context. it would need a demo replica.

Comment: I achieved it using this: `this.$timeout(() => this.config.Uri = '/api/image/300/500?latitude=${this.marker.getPosition().lat()}&longitude=${this.marker.getPosition().lng()}');`

Comment: google api callback runs out of angular context so you have to manually trigger use timeout or q.when etc.. But there details were not in the question. However best approach would be to abstract the google api call in an angular service and use `$q` to return the results. You would not need to make the manual digest cycle or timeout etc.. then. Check out this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639076/data-in-callback-when-using-controller-as-pattern-in-angular/33639255#33639255

Comment: Thanks so much for going the extra mile that will really help - would rather not do it manually.